# Como receber os dados de entrada de um programa em C vindos de um arquivo?

Tags: c, arquivo

Tenho um programa em C. Vamos supor que o nome dele compilado seja `a.out` (padrão).

Quando uso o seguinte comando para executá-lo...

```
./a.out < arquivo.txt
```

...como faço para ler o conteúdo do `arquivo.txt` dentro do programa (na função `main` mesmo)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente o que você precisa fazer é ler o `stdin` que é de onde virá os dados do arquivo. Uma implementação simplificada seria essa:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024
 
int main(void) {
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0ILcpw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ayawfomi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/GetStdin.c).

Desta forma o que vier pelo *pipe* do sistema operacional será impresso na tela. O *pipe* pegará uma fonte de dados, pode ser um arquivo mas pode ser outra fonte também.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu testei, mas não imprimiu nada. Então removi o `if`, compilei e tentei executar de novo mas dá um erro: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Eu fiz uma mudança, eu tinha comido bola, dava para fazer algo mais simples. Ainda não garanto que está ok porque não tenho como testar aqui mas se não der certo, me fale o problema que eu tento resolver.

Comment: Agora deu certo! Obrigado.